# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass When Looping Through Ruby Array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a hash of values that I am trying to loop through to display the values in my view.

The hash is set up as:

```
{:position=>#<Position id: 2, user_id: 1, title: "Something", city: "Denver", state: "CO",   
created_at: "2012-07-06 02:55:42", updated_at: "2012-07-06 02:55:42">, :experience=>[#
<Experience id: 4, user_id: 1, position_id: 2, description: "Did some stuff", created_at: 
"2012-07-02 06:24:33", updated_at: "2012-07-02 06:24:33">, #<Experience id: 6, user_id: 1, 
position_id: 2, description: "Did other stuff", created_at: "2012-07-02 06:24:33", 
updated_at: "2012-07-02 06:24:33">]}
```

It is created by taking ActiveRecord results and inserting them into a hash (if you want more details, I am happy to add them).

In my view, I attempt to loop through the hash:

```
<% for i in 0..@positions.length %>
  <%= @positions[i][:position][:title] %>
  <%= @positions[i][:position][:city] %>
<% end %>
```

When I open it in the browser, I get an error `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`.  If I only use `@positions[i]`, it will dump out the raw hash (first one, then second, and so on).  It's when I add `[:position]`, it doesn't work.  I can access the values in the console using `@positions[0][:position][:title]`.  When I tried writing the loop in console, I got the same error.

I know that `i` is counting because I can have it display the value in the browser and it is working correctly.

I have tried using `@positions.each do |job|` but ran into the same error.  I tried adding another indices in other places: `@positions[i][:position][0]`.

Basically, I have two models: Position and Experience.  Experience is a child to Position.  I want to get Experience for a given Position but only certain experience like ones that occur within a certain time frame.  There is most likely a better approach to this and I just don't know it so I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have an object of Postion class assigned to the key **:position**. So you access title and city through accessor methods and not with `[]`.

```
<% @positions.each do |job| %>
  <%= job[:position].title %>
  <%= job[:position].city %>
<% end %>
```